# How to introduce a Regular Expression abbreviation into a Regular Expression in Lex?

Tags: regex, lex

I have the following RE abbreviation:

```
word  [\x21-\x22\x24-\x2F\x3A-\x3F\x5B-\x5E\x60\x7B\-\x7E]
```

Now i need to introduce the word in the following Regular Expression:

```
[@][0-9a-zword][@]
```

So i could have, for example, the following phrases:

```
@0@
@r@
@!@
```

How can i say that it can either be a digit, a char from a to z or that "word" i defined before?

Comment: If you're using flex, you can write `[@][0-9a-z]{+}{word}[@]`. Flex also defines the `{-}` operator for difference between two sets, so you could also have written `[@][[:alnum:]]{-}[[:upper:]]{+}{word}[@]`. See http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html.  (Whether or not you are using flex, you could write `@` instead of `[@]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"@"([0-9a-z]|({word}))"@"
```

you can't expand a defined name into a set-match, as that does not in general make any sense.  Use `|` and parenthesis to get alteratives with proper grouping.

Be careful with AT&T lex (as opposed to flex) as it just substitutes the definition directly, so as with a C macro, you may need extra parens to get the precedence right.